# Mocking Repositories to test Service in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

I occurred some failures after trying to mock repositories to unit test my services in Spring-Boot
Thats what I have (simplified)

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class UserTest{


    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Mock
    private UserRepostiory userRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       User user = new User(1L, "email@email", "name");
        when(userRepostitory.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
    }


    @Test
    public void findUserByIdReturnsUser() {

        User user = userService.getById(1L); => always throws error in Service, that no User is found with that Id, it calls the regular Repository: mock does nothing
        assertEquals(1L,user.getId());

    }
}
```

But I never get the User returned when the service calls the repo. I am kinda new to Unit Testing, and I am pretty sure, that I miss something here.

Answer (score 1):

In the setUp you do:

```
when(userRepostitory.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
```

But in the Test you call

```
User user = userService.getById(1L);
```

Either mock getById or call findById

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my Service getById(..) I simply call userRepository.findById(). Is this not possible to mock the repository for the whole test scope/appcontext? What I want to do: I want to call service.getById(..), the service calls userRepo.findById(..) and I want the Repo to return the mock inside of the service

Answer (score 0):

"Repostiory" | "Repostitory" looks like a typo error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Repostiory" | "Repostitory" Neither is the spelling I expect, so you would have to explain in more detail how a typo can cause this problem and how the other spelling can fix it. Also, please avoid asking rhetoric questions in answer posts, they risk being mistaken for being questions instead of answers.

Answer (score 0):

First, If you are looking for unit tests then @SpringBootTest should be removed. There is no need to load the spring context while running unit tests.

I think the below code should work for you,

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class UserTest{


    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Mock
    private UserRepostiory userRepository;


    @BeforeEach //should be chosen as per your requirement
    public void setUp() {
       User user = new User(1L, "email@email", "name");
        when(userRepostitory.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
    }

    @Test
    public void findUserByIdReturnsUser() {
        User user = userService.getById(1L); => always throws error in Service, that no User is found with that Id, it calls the regular Repository: mock does nothing
        assertEquals(1L,user.getId());

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Annotate the test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`

Comment: NOt required anymore